# Run Maven project inside Docker Container with run time parameters

Tags: java, docker, selenium, maven

I have a Testng Selenium Project that is build using Maven. I am running this maven project using Maven Surefire plugin like this:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
            <configuration>
                <forkMode>never</forkMode>
                <useFile>true</useFile>
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                <!-- Suite testng xml file to consider for test execution-->
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>${suiteXmlFile}</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

**What I need to do?**
I need to run this Selenium project inside Docker Container. I need to move the complete source code to the container and run it from there. While running, I will be passing the path of testng xml file, that particular test alone should run. Post run, I need to take the result from docker image to local system (which we can do using docker cp ...).

**What I have done so far?**
I have created a docker image with maven, chrome, chromedriver. At run time, I am passing the testng XML file path and as expected that particular test case alone is running. But....
Once the program gets completed, the docker container is getting closed. docker ps shows no running containers. So, am not able to see the report.

**What I want?**
So, I want a way to avoid container from getting closed after the execution so that I can go into the docker container and see the report.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM kshivaprasad/java
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade --fix-missing -y
RUN apt-get install -y curl
RUN apt-get install -y p7zip \
    p7zip-full \
    unace \
    zip \
    unzip

# Install Chrome for Selenium
RUN curl http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/google-chrome-stable_83.0.4103.116-1_amd64.deb -o /chrome.deb
RUN dpkg -i /chrome.deb || apt-get install -yf
RUN rm /chrome.deb

# Install chromedriver for Selenium
RUN mkdir -p /app/bin
RUN curl https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/83.0.4103.39/chromedriver_linux64.zip -o /tmp/chromedriver.zip \
    && unzip /tmp/chromedriver.zip -d /app/bin/ \
    && rm /tmp/chromedriver.zip

ARG MAVEN_VERSION=3.6.3

# 2- Define a constant with the working directory
ARG USER_HOME_DIR="/root"

# 3- Define the SHA key to validate the maven download
ARG SHA=c35a1803a6e70a126e80b2b3ae33eed961f83ed74d18fcd16909b2d44d7dada3203f1ffe726c17ef8dcca2dcaa9fca676987befeadc9b9f759967a8cb77181c0

# 4- Define the URL where maven can be downloaded from
ARG BASE_URL=http://apachemirror.wuchna.com/maven/maven-3/${MAVEN_VERSION}/binaries

# 5- Create the directories, download maven, validate the download, install it, remove downloaded file and set links
RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/maven /usr/share/maven/ref \
  && echo "Downlaoding maven" \
  && curl -fsSL -o /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz ${BASE_URL}/apache-maven-${MAVEN_VERSION}-bin.tar.gz \
  \
  && echo "Checking download hash" \
  && echo "${SHA}  /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz" | sha512sum -c - \
  \
  && echo "Unziping maven" \
  && tar -xzf /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz -C /usr/share/maven --strip-components=1 \
  \
  && echo "Cleaning and setting links" \
  && rm -f /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz \
  && ln -s /usr/share/maven/bin/mvn /usr/bin/mvn

# 6- Define environmental variables required by Maven, like Maven_Home directory and where the maven repo is located
ENV MAVEN_HOME /usr/share/maven
ENV MAVEN_CONFIG "$USER_HOME_DIR/.m2"

COPY src /app/src
COPY pom.xml /app
COPY testng /app/testng
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /app/bin/chromedriver
#RUN mvn -f /app/pom.xml clean package
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

That entrypoint.sh file is used to send the argument at run time. It consists of:

```
#!/bin/sh
mvn -f /app/pom.xml clean install -DsuiteXmlFile=$1
```

**How I run this?**

```
docker build -t my_image .
docker run -it my_image module/testng.xml
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just need to need bash command in the shell file (entrypoint.sh). It worked fine for me.

```
#!/bin/sh
mvn -f /app/pom.xml clean install -DsuiteXmlFile=$1
/bin/bash
```

Answer (score 0):

This process would be very time consuming when it comes to the quick time to market. I would suggest use zalenium https://opensource.zalando.com/zalenium/ in order to run your selenium script in the docker container and it has various features too like viewing the ongoing execution and retrieving the reports.

Comment: Some of the key features I am in need of are: Parallel execution, Able to run across different browser versions and screen sizes. But with Zalenium, running across different browser version doesn't seem to be possible - https://github.com/zalando/zalenium/issues/180. Could you please let me know any other way?